# Скрыть процесс сжатия zip

Tags: vbscript

Пишу скрипт на **VBS**, который создаёт файл **zip-контейнер**, читает файлы в папке и копирует их в этот **zip-контейнер**. При запуске скрипта *(cmd (cscript script.vbs "параметры") )* при старте архивации в **zip** появляется окно процесса сжатия. **Как скрыть окно процесса сжатия zip?**

Comment: так запускайте скрипт не через обработчик команд **cmd.exe**, а через **cscript.exe**. Как запускать скрытые скрипты - это уже другой, решенный ранее вопрос.

Comment: Я создал **bat** файл, в котором указал: `cscript //nologo Путь к скрипту\script.vbs "Путь к папке, которую архивируем" "Путь к создаваемому файлу zip" "Остальные параметры"`. Как ещё можно запустить скрипт **vbs**?

Comment: Да способов много: создать задание (schtasks.exe). Запустить через wscript.exe, запустить в другом сеансе и т.д. Я уже написал, что скрытное исполнение VBS - это решённая задача, ответы есть на SO. Вы пишете в вопросе, что проблема с VBS-скриптом, а потом выясняется, что запускаете batch-файл.  В чём конкретно проблема-то?

Comment: @Daemon-5 Проблема в том, что имею код по паковке файлов и папок в zip-контейнер: `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items()
SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS = 64
source.Filter SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, FileFilter
objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere f, cFlags
Do Until objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).Items().Count = source.Count
   WScript.Sleep 500
Loop`

Comment: Когда начинают паковаться файлы выскакивает окно windows: Сжатие, вместе с прогресс баром, мне нужно скрыть это окно